# How can ı change elements in modal by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a bootstrap modal and ı need to change some elments in that modal.
how can ı reach the elements in the modal?

this is my modal and modal button:

```
<button name="degistir" type="button" id="gunmodal" value="<?php echo $postacek["product_id"]; ?>"  class="btn btn-outline-success btn-primary" data-bs-whatever="ali" data-bs-toggle="modal"data-bs-target="#inlineForm" >Düzenle</button>

<div class="modal fade text-left modalss"  id="inlineForm" tabindex="-1"
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel33" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable"
    role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel33">Güncelleme</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
                <i data-feather="x"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form id="guncelleformveri" >
            <div id="formveri" class="bg-primary" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is jquery ajax method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){//kategori ekle
      $("#gunmodal").on("click", function(){ // buton idli elemana tıklandığında
        var val=$(this).val();
        alert(val);
         
        
        $.ajax({
          url:'veri.php', // serileştirilen değerleri ajax.php dosyasına
          type:'POST', // post metodu ile 
          data:val, // yukarıda serileştirdiğimiz gonderilenform değişkeni 
          success:function(e){ // gonderme işlemi başarılı ise e değişkeni ile gelen değerleri aldı
            $("#formveri").html("").html(e); // div elemanını her gönderme işleminde boşalttı ve gelen verileri içine attı
            
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: But it didn't work. I can get product id but i can't get anything from veri.php

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console or the network tab?

Comment: Nope i didn't. Just i get a blank modal i try to fill that modal but it didn't work.

Comment: Add the code in the `veri.php` file to the question as well. Maybe that's where the issue is.

Comment: I didn't add in this webpage. how i can add here.

Comment: what is the value inside  `e` ? try  `console.log` from console

Comment: I am gonna try.

Comment: '<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$db = conopen();

if (isset($_POST['val'])) {
 $id=$_POST['val'];
  echo "geldi";}'    ---> this is veri.php nad console. log(e) result is = ""   ı mean its null